# How to get Docker Compose local cache export to work?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, devops

I am try to cache the docker compose build on a local location.
For some reason docker compose is not using the `docker-container` driver and the local cache export fails with the error message:

> cache export feature is currently not supported for docker driver. Please switch to a different driver (eg. "docker buildx create --use").

My current setup looks like this:

`docker-compose.yml`

```
name: "dev"
services:
  my-service:
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      cache_from:
        - type=local,src=./.docker-cache/
      cache_to:
        - type=local,dest=./.docker-cache/,mode=max
```

then I run those commands:

- `docker context create tls-environment`
- `docker buildx create --name multiarch-builder --driver docker-container --use tls-environment --use`
- `docker compose build` <-- errors

I expect no error and successful `.docker-cache` folder created.

This works on my local setup just fine. But fails in the Gitlab Pipeline.
What am I missing?